# Javascript if else statement with redirecting to page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, redirect

I have this HTML page with javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    function websiteBeoordelen () {
        var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
        if (code == 101101) {
            document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
                location.href = "http://google.nl";
            }
        }
        else {
            document.write("The code is wrong, try again!");
        }   
    }
    while (code != 101101) {
        document.getElementById('button').onclick = websiteBeoordelen;
    }
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">

<table border="0">
<form method="post">
<label>Code:</label><input name="code" id="code" type="text" class="input"/>
<br /><br />
<label>&nbsp;</label><input name="submit" type="submit" id="button" value="Login" class="button" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</form>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to redirect the user to a page if he or she had the correct code. If the code is incorrect, I want to have it written underneath the button on the same page, but the user has to be able to try again.

I know this might be a very simple problem to solve, but I've just started working with Javascript so it will mean a great deal if you guys can help me out so I can understand Javascript better.

Comment: The `while` loop is just an infinite loop. You don’t actually need the loop, I think. Remove it and only leave the `document.getElementById('button').onclick = websiteBeoordelen;` line.

Comment: `code` in while loop is `undefined`.

Comment: Lose that while loop for a start. And bind that function to your onclick inside the script once only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, change your code to this:

```
    window.onload = function () {
    function websiteBeoordelen () {
        var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
        if (code == 101101) {
            document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
                location.href = "http://google.nl";
            }
        }
        else {
            document.write("The code is wrong, try again!");
        }
      return false;   
    }
   document.getElementById('button').onclick = websiteBeoordelen;
};
```

Just removing the while loop would make it work.

Added return false to prevent page refresh.

Comment: The `onclick` listener is not necessary. The line saying `document.getElementById('button').onclick = websiteBeoordelen;` instead of the `while` loop is sufficient.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wanted to introduce new way for him.

Comment: Then it’s better to introduce him to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Notice, that the click listener is on a submit button. A pending server call will prevent changes to `location.href`. And not even mentioning the result of `document.write`, if the entered code wouldn't match ...

Comment: It still doesn't work, when I submit a wrong code, nothing happens, the page just refreshes, and also when I submit the correct code

Comment: @MoustafaS nope, still nothing. If I submit a wrong code, the page with "The code is wrong, try again!" flashes but then the page is just refreshing. And when I submit the correct code, the page is only refreshing

Comment: @Tyrion Did you include the line of return false; ?

Comment: @MoustafaS yes, now wrong code works! But still refreshing when submitting the correct code

Comment: @MoustafaS When submitting the correct code, first nothing happens, not even refreshing. But then clicking the button for the second time the page just refreshes

Comment: Do you want to redirect on correct code ? since your code will require 2 clicks, if you want to just redirect, using this  if (code == 101101) {
                location.href = "http://google.nl";
        }

Comment: @MoustafaS Ooh I see, that was the problem haha! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code

```
window.onload = function () {//good idea to wrap
    function websiteBeoordelen () {
        var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
        if (code == 101101) {
            document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
                //it will (supposedly) work on NEXT click
                location.href = "http://google.nl";
            }
        }
        else {
            //never use document.write. 
            //in this case it adds text inside <head> section
            document.write("The code is wrong, try again!");
        }   
    }
    while (code != 101101) {//no need to create infinite loop
        document.getElementById('button').onclick = websiteBeoordelen;
    }
};

//What works.
window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
     if(document.getElementById("code").value == '101101')
        location.href = "http://google.nl";
     else
        //Create a div or p to show message
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'The code is wrong, try again!';
     return false;//prevent form submission
   }//.onclick
}//window.onload
//End Of Code.
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of doing the ".onclick = " try this:

```
document.getElementById('button').setAttribute('onclick' , 'websiteBeoordelen();");
```

Also the value is a string so:

append a + "" to the integer above